# Problem building Festival (Text to Speech) on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, text-to-speech, gnu-make, festival

I set up a Ubuntu VM today just to build [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) on Ubuntu (I never ran it before) Then I did the following setups

1. On the Terminal window I wrote following to install GNU C++ Compiler

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
2. To test the g++ I wrote a sample hello world and compiled it using g++ and run it and it worked as expected.
3. I downloaded all the files from listed on [festival download page](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/downloads/festival/2.1/)
4. Unpacked all to the home directory(~) using

   ```
   tar -zxvf *.tar.gz
   ```
5. Then wrote following 3 commands to configure and make speech_tools

   ```
   cd speech_tools

   ./configure

   make
   ```

But make returns with following errors

```
/lib -leststring -lcurses -ldl -lncurses -lm -lstdc++ -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [ch_lab] Error 1
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

What am I missing? being a newbie to Ubuntu or any other Unix platform I may missed some important configuration, before that I have successfully built festival on my windows machine using Cygwin.

Comment: I tried the same on CentOS as well and here is the same problem, unable to find those two libs or whatever they are. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to install the development packages for `libncurses`. Try

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: It worked, The error is gone but now its saying ... 

../bin/festival: error while loading shared libraries: libestbase.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [festival.options] Error 127

Comment: the above mentioned file is placed in ~/speech_tools/lib how to tell the ~/festival/make that the you can find the lib in above mentioned directories???

Comment: I changed the ~/speech_tools/config/config file and replaced #SHARED=2 with SHARED=1, And Its worked.